# Rep -10 without any explanation

Tags: support, reputation

I just logged in and found out that I got a reputation of 811 when I was previously 821. I checked my reputation tab and nothing... why has this happened. I am just scared it will happen again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the questions you answered was deleted, so the reputation you got for your answer went with it.

You can confirm this by checking the "show removed posts" checkbox on the Reputation tab in your profile.